# How to write quotation marks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I want to do the following, but don't know how to write the quotation marks

```
allSearchResults[0]="<li><a href="CXS101289/"> CXS101289/</a></li>";
```

It shall be quotation marks where the currently are.

Comment: Escape the inlying quotes: `\"`

Comment: Or use single quotes `'` as 'outer' quotes.

Answer (score 20):

### Two ways <sup>times two</sup>

1. **mix single and double quotes:**

   ```
   // single outside, double inside quotes
   allSearchResults[0] = '<li><a href="CXS101289/">CXS101289/</a></li>';
   ```

   or

   ```
   // double outside, single inside quotes
   allSearchResults[0] = "<li><a href='CXS101289/'>CXS101289/</a></li>";
   ```
2. **use one set of quotes but escape inside ones:**

   ```
   // double escaped quotes
   allSearchResults[0] = "<li><a href=\"CXS101289/\">CXS101289/</a></li>";
   ```

   or

   ```
   // single escaped quotes
   allSearchResults[0] = '<li><a href=\'CXS101289/\'>CXS101289/</a></li>';
   ```

First approach with mixing is usually easier, because it presents less work since you only have to change the opening and closing quote.

Comment: What if the content is dynamic? What I mean is, suppose "CXS101289" is coming from database as "CXS'101289"?

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the quotes inside the a tag.

```
allSearchResults[0]="<li><a href=\"CXS101289/\"> CXS101289/</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can escape them like:

```
allSearchResults[0]="<li><a href=\"CXS101289/\"> CXS101289/</a></li>";
```

or use the other quotes :

```
allSearchResults[0]="<li><a href='CXS101289/'> CXS101289/</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
allSearchResults[0]="<li><a href='CXS101289/'> CXS101289/</a></li>";
```

or

```
allSearchResults[0]='<li><a href="CXS101289/"> CXS101289/</a></li>';
```

or

```
allSearchResults[0]="<li><a href=\"CXS101289/\"> CXS101289/</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, newer and very nice method: Use "multiline strings"!

Writing it like this, with a backtick at the beginning and end of the string, you can use anything you like inside, and even make use of variable substitution:

```
let b = "myvar value";
let x = `
    <li class="myclass" onclick="myFunc('${b}')">
        ${b}
    </li>
`;
```

That case is hard to do otherwise, mixing quotation marks within the string.